# How do I make a Live USB without destroying my Windows computer?

Tags: windows

Unlike every other post I have read, let me begin by saying that I am TERRIFIED of destroying my Windows 7 home system in the attempt of making a bootable Ubuntu Thumb Drive. I very specifically DO NOT want to attempt configuring a dual boot system.

What I am seeking is a portable operating system on a thumb drive, through which I can run my COREL software via VirtualBox-4.1.16-78094-Win. I want to be able to use my own software on my work computer without any worries about screwing up the host system anywhere I go.

Supposedly, I just made a bootable Thumb drive, having successfully loaded the ISO for ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386 using Pendrivelinux's Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.0.1

However, all that I get is a Thumb Drive that wants to install Ubuntu onto my PC's HDD.

I am not finding any clear path to this end in the posts I am reading.

Like it or not, Windows is a fact of life for me. The goal is to be able to use my software on my work PC without doing anything intrusive that will cost me my job. If I have a meltdown on my PC at home trying to make this happen, it will be nearly as bad.

Is this even Do-Able? Can the process be made clear?

Thank You, Ubuntu World ...!

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key .What is the capacity of you Thumb Drive.To admins , possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot from the Live USB, you should be able to select Try Ubuntu. This option allows you to run Ubuntu from your USB, without installing it to your computer. If you want to save the changes you made to Ubuntu when you unplug the USB, you need to put Ubuntu on the USB again, but enable Persistance. Persistance allocates some space on the USB that allows you to save changes you make to the USB, such as installing packages or downloading files.